# Getting the path of a file from the project

Tags: c#

My structure is like this picture below:

[image]

How can I write a code that gets me the path to the highlighted one which is "ConenctionsList.xml" ?

I tried something like this but this take me to **bin** folder

```
this.XmlPlath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"ConnectionsList.XML");
```

Comment: those still go to BIN folder.

Comment: Do you want it to work only during development (i.e. while running from the bin folder) or do you expect it to work when deployed too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good that `XmlPath` points to the bin folder, the trick is to set `ConnectionList.xml` to be copied in the output. Just, enter its properties and set `Copy to Output` to `Always` or even better - `If Newer`.

**Note:** Imagine that your application will be deployed and your paths within the project or solution do not make sense in the deployed location. Only relative paths to the executable (or some assembly) are important (except if GAC registering or something similar is used).

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what the absolute path of that file is to reference it in code.  Referencing it by where it resides in Visual Studio is not adequate.  More often than not, if you are running a program and wish to read in a config file of some sort, the designer will put the configuration file in the same place as the executable and reference it using various methods, one of which is listed below:

```
string filename = "ConnectionsList.xml";
string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),filename);
```

Please reference links below, and other threads on Stack Overflow for any additional details.  This general topic is addressed in numerous places.

[MSDN GetCurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)
[MSDN Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx)